# Print an organizational chart to PDF from JSON data?

Tags: pdf, printing, charts

I've been searching for a few days and haven't found quite what I need yet.

I've got a tool I'm working on that displays a person in a sort of visual hierarchy of the company (from the CEO down the reporting chain to the person, and then any direct reports they have).

I've got a nice JSON string that I'm using for the current plugin, but a request we are getting often is a printable version of the interactive org chart.

I can pull the JSON data when requested, and can reformat it however I might need, but does anyone know of a tool that'll make a nice organization chart in a ready to print (or PDF maybe?) format that accepts JSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any PHP experience, you could use [pChart's extended capabilities](http://www.pchart.net/features-extended) to run your data through that and create a [Spring Chart](http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.spring.pspring.html) that resembles and org chart.

You could also check out [Google's Charting API for Org Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart).

Neither of these get you directly to PDF's, but if you're running Chrome or CutePDF it's easy to print as a PDF.

Comment: I'm currently using theJIT.org's spacetree, which has a canvas element. I'll look into pChart, but I think I'm going to end up using google's orgchart API to make a printable one and keep the spacetree for out interactive one.

Comment: Sounds good, glad I could help. Feel free to give that Answer button a whirl if I answered the question.

Comment: Google's charts print out fine, so that's that for me I guess. It's a bit more work to use them, but ended up being worth the effort.